# regexp_replace for oracle to replace https not working

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

anyone know why does RegExp works on simulators but not really in oracle?

should replace // with / except on https://

```
SELECT regexp_replace (url_link,'(?<!https:)\/\/','\/'), url_link
FROM URL_TABLE;
```

changes

```
https://pet/green//car/plane//garden
```

to

```
https://pate/gren/car/plane/gardn
```

thank you

Comment: Because [Oracle only supports some of the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html) that other platforms and simulators do.

Comment: There are different styles of regex. Oracle's regex engine doesn't support lookahead.

Comment: Is "https" the real marker, or is it the colon before the two slashes? What should be the output from `http://my.website//my.page`? Also, do you care if https is at the beginning of the string, or do you need to protect it also further out in the string? If it's general (rather than specifically for `https://`), what should be done with THREE (or more) slashes in a row? In particular: `file:/// .....`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use a Non-Colon Character List for the Character Preceding the `//` in the REGEXPR_REPLACE Pattern String**

This is the same as Littlefoot's solution except to make sure we do not replace the first `//` with the `:` preceding.

We just indicate that we do not want a match with the non-colon character list, `[^:]`, and then encapsulate this in a character group (place this in a parethesis).

In our replace string, we just reference this character group with `\1` which translates as the first character group.

```
SCOTT@db>SELECT
  2      regexp_replace('https://pet/green//car/plane//garden','([^:])//','\1/')  http_url
  3  FROM
  4      dual;

http_url                                 
------------------------------------
https://pet/green/car/plane/garden
```

---

**Addendum**

As a side note to this pattern matching problem, it sure would be nice if Oracle's implementation of regular expression did have (negative) lookahead or (negative) lookbehind.

Here is an example of this problem with Vim's regular expression matching:

`\(https:\|http:\)\@<!` = negative lookbehind for "https:" or "http:" using alternation operator

`\/\/`                  = double forward slashed pattern

We see matching `//` highlighted in blue

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not very smart, but works (kind of):

```
SQL> with test as (select 'https://pet/green//car/plane//garden' url from dual)
  2  --
  3  select
  4    regexp_replace(url, '//', '/', 8) res1,
  5    regexp_replace(url, '//', '/', instr(url, '//') + 1) res2
  6  from test;

RES1                               RES2
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
https://pet/green/car/plane/garden https://pet/green/car/plane/garden

SQL>
```

[added Gary_W's suggestion as RES2]

Comment: You could replace the hardcoded `8` with `instr(url, '//')+1` to make it smarter (start the replace 1 character after the first double-slashes found:-)

Comment: Certainly, @Gary_W; I'm also sure that someone experienced in regular expressions might make some kind of *magic* and show us something really smart.

Comment: hmm.. thank you, I tried it and it worked :) good to have these tricks in mind